# How do we know if an additional factor has improved the predictive power of a Fama French 3 factor equity model?

Tags: equities, factor-models, fama-french, factor-investing, opentaps-climate

We're building a multi-factor model for climate risk by adding an additional factor for carbon risk on top of a Fama and French 3 factor model.  This is open source at https://github.com/opentaps/open-climate-investing

We've tested the additional carbon risk factor and found that it increases the R2 of the regressions: https://github.com/opentaps/open-climate-investing/issues/4

Is this sufficient to say that the additional factor has improved the predictive power of the model?  Or should there be other tests done?

Comment: Hey Si, Since you posted this question 2 years and 2 months ago, I am curious as to whether you found the anwser to this question. Is the increased R2 a reliable indicator of increased predictive power? And for what kind of regression? FMB?